# Multiple AggregateResult Querys

Tags: salesforce, apex, apex-code

Hi guys,
I'm currently trying to join two objects in a same query or result.
My question is if it's possible to show or debug the sum of FIELD A FROM LEAD + sum of FIELD B FROM two different Objects. 
Here's an example I'm working on:
Btw I really appreciate your time and comments, and if i'm making a mistake pls let me know, thank you.

```
public static void example() {

   String sQueryOne;
   String sQueryTwo;
   AggregateResult[] objOne;
   AggregateResult[] objTwo;

   //I tried to save the following querys into a sObject List
   List<SObject> bothObjects = new List<SObject>();

   sQueryOne = 'Select Count(Id) records, Sum(FieldA) fieldNA From Lead';
   objOne = Database.query(sQueryOne);
   sQueryTwo = 'Select Count(Id) records, Sum(FieldA) fieldNB From Opportunity';
   objTwo = Database.query(sQueryTwo);

   bothObjects.addAll(objOne);
   bothObjects.addAll(objTwo);

   for(sObject totalRec : bothObjects) {
       //There's a Wrapper(className) I created which contains some variables(totalSum)
       className finalRes = new className();
       finalRes.totalSum = (Integer.valueOf(fieldNA)) + (Integer.valueOf(fieldNB));
       System.debug('The sum is: '+finalRes.totalSum);
```

> For example if I call a System debug with the previous variable finalRes.totalSum it's just showing the first value(fieldNA) duplicated.

The following debug shows the current values of the sObject List which I want to sum for example FIELD0 = from leads, FIELD0 = from Opportunities.

[image: Debug bothObjects variable]

```
   }
}
```

Comment: You have `bothObjects.addAll(objOne);` twice, copy-paste error probably. What happens when you fix it?

Comment: Oh yep, it was copy-paste error. It's actually showing both results FIELDNA and FIELDNB but Idk how to join both results u know, I edited the poast adding an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You access the columns in `AggregateResult` by calling `get('columnAlias')`. If you didn't specify an alias they'll be autonumbered by SF as `expr0`, `expr1`... When in doubt you can always go `System.debug(results);`

Some more info: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm

This might give you some ideas:

```
List<AggregateResult> results = new List<AggregateResult>{
    [SELECT COUNT(Id) records, SUM(NumberOfEmployees) fieldA, SUM(AnnualRevenue) fieldB FROM Account],
    [SELECT COUNT(Id) records, SUM(Amount) fieldA, SUM(TotalOpportunityQuantity) fieldB FROM Opportunity],
    [SELECT COUNT(Id) records, SUM(NumberOfEmployees) fieldA, SUM(AnnualRevenue) fieldB FROM Lead]
    /* hey, not my fault these are only 2 standard numeric fields on Lead. 
    It doesn't matter that they're identical to Account fields, what matters is what their SUM(...) aliases are
    */
};

List<Decimal> totals = new List<Decimal>{0,0,0};

for(AggregateResult ar : results){
    totals[0] += (Decimal) ar.get('records');
    totals[1] += (Decimal) ar.get('fieldA');
    totals[2] += (Decimal) ar.get('fieldB');
}

System.debug(totals); // (636, 8875206.0, 9819762558.0) in my dev org
```

(I'm not saying it's perfect, your wrapper class sounds like better idea or maybe even `Map<String, Decimal>`. Depends what are you going to do with the results)

Comment: Thank you so much @eyescream for your answer, you gave me more ideas about how to resolve my problem, I appreciate that (y).
Regards.